# Button Is TextBlock?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I am using this function to recurse thru all the controls inside a `ListBoxItem` and I have both a `Button` and a `TextBlock` inside the `DataTemplate`. It always picks the Button instead of the `TextBlock`. Can anyone see whats wrong with my function?

```
Private Function FindVisualChild(ByVal obj As DependencyObject) As TextBlock
 Dim result As TextBlock = Nothing
 For i As Integer = 0 To VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj) - 1
  Dim child As DependencyObject = TryCast(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i), DependencyObject)
  If Not child Is Nothing AndAlso TypeOf child Is DependencyObject Then
    If TypeOf child Is TextBlock Then
      Dim tbl As TextBlock = TryCast(child, TextBlock)
      If Not tbl Is Nothing Then result = tbl
    Else
      Dim tbl As TextBlock = FindVisualChild(child)
      If Not tbl Is Nothing Then result = tbl : Exit For
    End If
  End If
Next
Return result
```

End Function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems simple, but it works! Does not explain why it was confused with types below this line

```
Private Function FindVisualChild(ByVal obj As DependencyObject) As TextBlock
Dim result As TextBlock = Nothing
For i As Integer = 0 To VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj) - 1
  Dim child As DependencyObject = TryCast(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i), DependencyObject)
  If TypeOf child Is Button Then Continue For 'fixes it
  If Not child Is Nothing AndAlso TypeOf child Is DependencyObject Then
    If TypeOf child Is TextBlock Then
      Dim tbl As TextBlock = TryCast(child, TextBlock)
      If Not tbl Is Nothing Then result = tbl
    Else
      Dim tbl As TextBlock = FindVisualChild(child)
      If Not tbl Is Nothing Then result = tbl : Exit For
    End If
  End If
Next
Return result
```

End Function